# Closing a Jquery Dialog after a Document is returned via ActionResult

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, document, actionresult

I have a JQuery Dialog that is used to pass some information to the server. The ActionResult Method then generates a document. This is then returned to the browser. All good so far.

However, I am wanting to close the dialog when the document is returned.

Comment: are you using ajax? if so, then closing the document can be done in success function of ajax.

Comment: When you call *"ASP.NET MVC"* framework as simply *"MVC"*, it is like referring to IE as *"the internet"*.

Comment: You mean IE isn't the internet? ;) Noted and thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

if u using ajax call u can use success function

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'url',      
    success: function (data) {
        close dialog here.
    }
})
```

if u using mvc ajax from u can use success function of this helper

```
@Ajax.BeginForm("", new AjaxOptions { OnSuccess="close_dialog()"})
```

and if u submit the form without ajax u can send some messegge to view and close the dialog or just dont open it:)

```
 [HttpPost]       
    public ActionResult YourAction(UrModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //Use any stuff to send the message to View 
            ViewBag.close_dialog = true;
            ViewData["close_dialog"] = true;
            //or temp data or modelstate or somethins else.
        }
        return View(model);
    }
```

and in view

```
<script type ="text/javascript">
@if (ViewBag.close_dialog)
{
    <text>
//javscript here
close_dialog();
    </text>
}
```

Comment: OnSuccess is called even if ModelState is invalid. Mvc treats "Success" as HTTP 200 OK, but I might bet that we're not chasing it by http status. Its the Validation what really defines if an "request" was "successful" or not.